# Save .dbf as .xls using python

Tags: python, save

Is there a simple way to save a .dbf file as a .xls file using python. I just want to open the .dbf file in python and then immediately do a 'save as .xls'. I'm trying to avoid looping through records in a dbf and writing to the excel table.

Something like:

```
fileobj = open(outFolder + "\\" + "TABLE.dbf")
fileobj.save(outFolder + "\\" + "TABLE.xls")
```

I've searched around the internet, but haven't found anything, so I thought I'd try a post.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Take a look at [dbfpy](http://dbfpy.sourceforge.net/) and [cvs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) python modules.  I'm sure you can script something simple with these two packages.  Excel can read csv files.

Comment: @Pablo Maurin: If you make that comment an answer, I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: Thanks Pablo. I am trying to get it to save as a .xls. Reason being...my end user is completely computer illiterate and only knows how to open a .xls file when they see it, so I'm trying to make things easy on his head without going through the process of other file types....sounds dumb, but he writes my pay cheques :)

Comment: @ChristopheD.  Since I'm not going to bother writing the script, I'm going to leave it a comment.  But thank you.

Comment: Then follow it up with [py-csv2xls](http://py-csv2xls.sourceforge.net/).  Or use .xls extension as suggested in [Convert a CSV file to a XLS file on the linux command line?](http://serverfault.com/questions/73987/convert-a-csv-file-to-a-xls-file-on-the-linux-command-line).

Answer (score 1):

If you were willing to accept using the Python `csv` module (which would involve looping through dbf records and writing csv), consider going straight to `xls` by using [xlwt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt).

Alternatively, could your client could be shown how to open dbf files in Excel?

Comment: Thanks people. I went with writing each record. I got a few points from the links you guys offered. Thanks!